# SQL Base32 Conversion

Tags: sql, syntax

I am writing a SQL Function that will take in a decimal and return the base32 representation of that decimal.

My problem is with the decimal to ascii conversion.

I am allowed to run the following query and return an ascii character

"SELECT CHAR( 65 )" which returns "A"

However in my function when I am trying to build my output string of letters, I am having trouble casting a bigint into a char, then concatenate that char to the end of a another char(which would be my output).

Sample line of code: "SET @OutputChar = @OutputChar + CAST( ( @Output + 55 ) AS CHAR(255) )"

What is the proper way to cast a bigint to char and then concatenate that char to another?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you declaring @OutputChar?

If you have:

```
DECLARE @OutputChar CHAR(255)
```

then every time you concantenate, it will truncate it to 255.  CHAR includes the whitespace at the end, maybe you mean to use varchar instead of CHAR?

Comment: You pointed out the error in my logic. I was allocating 255 in size for the char, which when I go to concatenate it would be 255 + 255, and cut off the concatenated char. I changed it from CHAR(255) to CHAR and this allowed the char to not be truncated. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @OutputChar = @OutputChar + CONVERT(varchar(255),@Output + 55)
```